# How to add two partially overlapping numpy arrays and extend the non-overlapping parts?

Tags: numpy, signal-processing, numpy-ndarray

I'm adding a short audio signal (1-D numpy array of a musical note) to roughly the end of a longer signal (the first part of the audio stream constructed so far). I'd like to add the overlapping part and extend the non-overlapping part. What is the most efficient way to achieve this? I can identify the overlapping part and add it to the main signal while concatenating the non-overlapping part, but I don't think this is sufficiently efficient. I also think make them the same size by padding with zeros is very memory inefficient. Is there a numpy or scipy function for achieving this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np arrays are contiguous memory blocks.  Those of `a` and `b` are almost guaranteed to *not* be contiguous with each other, so you really only have an option to extend one with a copy of the second or create a new object that creates the object you want.

I don't know your constraints, but I suspect you're trying to prematurely optimize.  Just write something clear first and optimize if it doesn't meet whatever needs you have:

```py
def add_signal(a, b, ai=0, bi=0):
    assert ai >= 0
    assert bi >= 0

    al = len(a)
    bl = len(b)
    cl = max(ai + al, bi + bl)
    c = np.zeros(cl)
    c[ai: ai + al] += a
    c[bi: bi + bl] += b
    return c
```

Example:

```py
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
add_signal(a, b, bi=len(a)-3)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  2., 13., 24., 35., 40.])
```